# Troubles with apache and virtual hosts

Tags: apache, debian, virtual, hosts

I have a BIG problem.
I have VPS with Debian OS, and LAMP installed. Fresh install. 
For control panel i using Webmin.
Now i trying to setup multiple sub-domains on my server using webmin for example:

```
downloads.my-domain.com
cpanel.my-domains.com
forum.my-domains.com
```

But problem what is happening is next, while i using no virtual hosts, everything works perfectly when i accessing it using my-domain.com, but when i add Virtual host, i cann access it but my-domain.com becomes unavilable because it redirects to virtual hosts i added. When i add more than 2 virtual hosts, problem is still here.
Also, when i try to access to virtual server for example downloads.my-domain.com, it redirects again to cpanel.my-domains.com
When i delete virtual hosts, access to my-domain.com is succesfull...

What i known:
 - That is not problem with my domain provider. I correctly added subdomains and added host record to my VPS IP.
 - I added unique name to every single virtual host.
 - There are no two same virtual hosts
 - Every virtaul hosts have own directory: for example: downloads.my-domain.com have own WWW dir: /var/downloads

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you post your question on [serrverfault](http://serverfault.com/) rather than here...

Comment: Thank you. I posted it there. I hope i will get help.

Comment: Hm, webmin forums might be more appropriate, as normally the apache config would be quite straightforward / not much that can go wrong. Or you can go the full virtualmin route if you're already using webmin.

Comment: I fixed that thanks. Look at answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting all exist virtual hosts and manualy adding these code to my httpd.conf for each virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@my-domain.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/download.my-domain.com"
        ErrorLog /var/www/error_download.log
        CustomLog /var/www/access_download.log common
        ServerName download.my-domain.com
        ServerAlias download
        <Directory "/var/www/download.my-domain.com">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So if you have(or you haved) same problem, just edit these lines to match your own criteria and use it.

You can use this editor/generator which i just created, to customize this code.
http://server2.elite7hackers.us/apps/vhosts/